# Using the DragDropTarget with a traditional Grid

Tags: silverlight, grid

Silverlight 4 now provides controls to handle Drag and Drop actions. All the Target Controls seem to inherit from DragDropTarget Like so

```
public class MyControlDragDropTarget : DragDropTarget<TItemsControlType,TItemsContainerType>
```

.
.
.

A number of controls have pre-defined DragDropTargets including the DataGrid, ListBox, Panels

Which is all very well, but I want to drag and drop from a grid **not** a datagrid, and there is no pre-defined one for a normal grid.

I actually want to drag a given row from the grid, but without a Container Type for a Grid I cannot work out how to define a DragDropTarget control for the grid.

Only way I can think is instead of using a grid - I use a listbox (for which there is a DragDropTarget) and then place a StackPanel or Grid in each row (which has one row of 'n' columns)

Anyone got any ideas

Ta in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "normal grid" is simply another form of panel, there is no need for specialised `DragDropTarget` for the `Grid`, the existing `PanelDragDropTarget` is sufficient for a "normal grid".

Its important grasp that the `Grid` does not support the concept of "rows containing cells containing UI elements".  The rows and columns of a Grid are entirely equal and are defined purely for layout purposes.  UIElement children of a Grid are laid out entirely independently of each other, there is no concept of a set of values belonging to either a column or a row that can be moved or operated on as a group (like picking up a row and dragging it).

Sounds like you have already got an answer for yourself, use the `ListBox` instead.

BTW, `DragDropTarget` isn't provided by Silverlight 4 but rather the Silverlight Toolkit.  This is an important distinction because the current quality band assigned to `DragDropTarget` is "Experimental".  You need to think carefully about this if you want to use such code in some production release of your own.

Comment: Ta - I'll do that but was wondering if having in effect 1 grid per row would be prohibitive. Although I'm likely to create a user control for the child objects - allowing for meta data to be stored against them.

Comment: @paulschapman:  Standard `Grid` elements are lightweight so if I'm understanding you correctly having one Grid per row would not be prohibitive.